# SwiftMailer attachement pdf generate by Dompdf dynamic

Tags: symfony, dompdf, mailer

First for any help :)

I work on Symfony 4.4 Framework and i have controller generate PDF and send it by mail attachement, but i want send pdf directly on controller and not stock file on system send it and delete them.

```
            $pdf = new Dompdf( $pdfOptions );
            $html = $this->render('recommendations/synthesePdf.html.twig', [
                'products' => $products,
                'recommendations' => $recommendations,
                'customer' => $customer,
                'cultureTotal' => $cultureTotal
            ]);
            $pdf->loadHtml( $html->getContent() );
            $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
            $pdf->render();

            //-- SEND PDF TO USER
            $message = (new \Swift_Message('Nouvelle recommendation disponible'))
                ->setFrom('send@example.com')
                //->setTo( $customer->getEmail() )
                ->setTo( '***' )
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'emails/recommendation.html.twig', [
                            'identity' => $customer->getIdentity()
                        ]
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                )
                ->attach( \Swift_Attachment::fromPath( $pdf->output() ) )
            ;
            $mailer->send($message);
```

Hi use $pdf->output / $pdf->getHtml but it's not working if you have any suggestion :)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use The FileSystem Component Of Symfony Like =>

1. Installation

   `composer require symfony/filesystem`
2. Usage

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

   $filesystem = new Filesystem();
   ```
3. Remove Files

   ```
   $filesystem->remove(['/path/to/file']);
   ```

in your case you can save the file pdf then send it and if the mail is sent you remove the file

Doc: [The Filesystem Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html)